# VSTO Addin Custom Dialog Box Responses

Tags: c#, dialog

I have an Outlook 2013 addin where I want to display a dialog box with `ShowDialog()`.  I understand how to do this, but I want to ask the user a question with 2 answers.  Meaning I want to customize what is on the buttons.  I also am not sure how to get a custom dialog result like that.  I was told I need to pass the Outlook window handle in as well and I'm somewhat confused on what methods I should use to get that.

I need help understanding how to customize my dialog buttons (which I assume can even be done in visual designer with Form) as well as how to get and test for a custom response.  For example I want to ask "Do you want A or B?"

An example would be most appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i don't misunderstand your need, in order to do this you should create a customized Form which this customized form inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form. add a new windows form and design it something like this:

```
    // label1
    // 
    this.label1.AutoSize = true;
    this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(70, 59);
    this.label1.Name = "label1";
    this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(137, 17);
    this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
    this.label1.Text = "Do you want A or B?";
    // 
    // button1
    // 
    this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(35, 121);
    this.button1.Name = "button1";
    this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
    this.button1.TabIndex = 1;
    this.button1.Text = "A";
    this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    // 
    // button2
    // 
    this.button2.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
    this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(149, 121);
    this.button2.Name = "button2";
    this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
    this.button2.TabIndex = 2;
    this.button2.Text = "B";
    this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
```

you can do this in  CustomForm.Designer or by clicking in each properties of components.
as you can see i set DialogResult of B as Ok (you can change it if you want), so you can achieve what you want by this:

```
  var frm = new CustomForm();//CustomForm is the name of your customized form
  DialogResult res = frm.ShowDialog();
  if (res == DialogResult.OK)
     {
          //do something, when user clicks on B
     }
```

Comment: Perfect thank you. So I just use the normal dialog result OK for one of them ya? this is exactly what I needed

Comment: @shenk, yes you can just set DialogResult.Ok to one of them, glad it fits your need.